# set custom font for webview in xamarin.forms for android and ios

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am using xamarin forms for my project. I am using webview for getting and displaying the content of web link like "{Weblink}". I am having the font family(Montserrat-Medium.ttf) locally in android Asset folder. I need to assign the custom font for the webview.
For android, the font is in Asset folder,
For iOS, the font is in Resource folder,

I am using the following code:

**WebView.xaml:**

```
<local:CoolContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:XXX"
                       xmlns:custom="clr-namespace:XXX"
             x:Class="XXX.Form.YYY" Title="YYY" EnableBackButtonOverride="True">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <ContentView>
                <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0">
                    <custom:CustomWebView x:Name="webview" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>
                </StackLayout>
        </ContentView>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</local:CoolContentPage>
```

**WebView.xaml.cs:**

```
var htmlSource = new HtmlWebViewSource();
htmlSource.Html = @"<html>
<head>
<style>
@font-face {
font-family: myFirstFont;
src: url('file:///android_asset/Montserrat-Medium.ttf');
}
div {
font-family: myFirstFont;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>" + {Weblink} + @"</body></html>";
htmlSource.BaseUrl = DependencyService.Get<IBaseUrl>().Get();
webview.Source = htmlSource;
```

**CustomWebView.cs:**

```
public class CustomWebView:WebView
    {
    }
```

**Renderer:
Android:**

```
[assembly: Dependency(typeof(BaseUrl_Android))]
namespace XXX.Droid.Services
{
    public class BaseUrl_Android : IBaseUrl
    {
        public string Get()
        {
            return "file:///android_asset/";
        }
    }
}
```

**Renderer:
iOS:**

```
[assembly: Dependency (typeof (BaseUrl_iOS))]

namespace XXX.iOS 
{
    public class BaseUrl_iOS : IBaseUrl 
    {
        public string Get () 
        {
            return NSBundle.MainBundle.BundlePath;
        }
    }
}
```

But in webview, i am having only default font, not custom font.
Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: Weblink means https://www.x...z.com

Comment: Did you try giving read/write permission in manifest file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the `.html` files into `Assets` in android project and set the Build Action to `AndroidAsset`.
And I add font `Karantina-Light.ttf` into folder `Assets`.

For example, I defined `index.html` in folder `Assets`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            @font-face {
            font-family: MyFont;
            src: url("file:///android_asset/Karantina-Light.ttf")
            }

            body {
            font-family: MyFont;
            font-size: medium;
            text-align: justify;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>Hello World</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

BaseUrl_Android.cs

```
public class BaseUrl_Android : IBaseUrl
    {
        public string Get()
        {
            return "file:///android_asset/";
        }
    }
```

The contentpage code is:

```
var urlSource = new UrlWebViewSource();
string url = DependencyService.Get<IBaseUrl>().Get();

string TempUrl = Path.Combine(url, "index.html");
urlSource.Url = TempUrl;
webview.Source = urlSource;
```

The result in android is:

[image]

You can refe to this thread: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/33404/set-custom-font-in-webview .

Answer (score 0):

Since you defined font-family for `div` you need to put your content inside `<div></div>`. Also, remove `file:///android_asset` so that this can work on iOS also:

```
htmlSource.Html = @"<html>
   <head>
      <style>
         @font-face {
         font-family: myFirstFont;
         src: url('Montserrat-Medium.ttf');
         }
         div {
         font-family: myFirstFont;
         }
      </style>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div>" + "https://www.x...z.com"
         + @"
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
";
```

If you want to define a font family for `body`, just replace `div` with `body`, and then you don't have to put your content inside `div`:

```
htmlSource.Html = @"
<html>
   <head>
      <style>
         @font-face {
         font-family: myFirstFont;
         src: url('Montserrat-Medium.ttf');
         }
         body {
         font-family: myFirstFont;
         }
      </style>
   </head>
   <body>" + {Weblink} + @"</body>
</html>
";
```

This will give you the output like this:

[image]